# Deploying Azure App Service within Azure App Service Environment using Terraform

Tags: azure, azure-devops, terraform, terraform-provider-azure, azure-automation

There seems to be plenty of resources/examples of deploying Azure App Services - but I was wondering if there was an example somewhere explaining:

How to deploy Azure App services within a specific Azure App Service Environment using Terraform? Is it simply pointing the application into the subnet that holds the ASE?

Thanks ahead of time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When deploying App Service Plan, you can specify App Service Environment it should be located in using `app_service_environment_id` attribute ([doc](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/app_service_plan#app_service_environment_id)).

Then you deploy App Service into that plan...

Comment: thanks, this answers my question!